# Record video with overlay view

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

Hi I am developing an Universal App. In which I am recording a video using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput. While recording the video I have displayed some random images on the overlay view. What I want to do is I want those overlay images along with the video recorded.
Can anybody help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also trying to show overlay view on recorded video. see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504094/how-to-record-video-with-overlay-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you get your overlay onto the screen, simply follow this tutorial:

[iOS Camera Overlay Example Using AVCaptureSession](https://web.archive.org/web/20200109090100/http://musicalgeometry.com/p/1273)

The next step would be calling the startVideoCapture method and there you have it.

Comment: When I clicked the link in your comment, its opening this page only.

Comment: The link above is a circular link back to this page.

Comment: woops... i fixed it. I can't quite remember, but i think i used a variant of this sourse code... its a great tutorial:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273

Comment: I am also trying to record video with overlay view. see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504094/how-to-record-video-with-overlay-view

Comment: Any idea for record video with overlay??